# Cannot use query.execute statement in VBA in ms access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I Have a saved query that I want to run from vba.  The query is called "211_AppendToBackdated_Tracer"

```
DoCmd.OpenQuery "211_AppendToBackdated_Tracer"   'This line works
CurrentDb.Execute "211_AppendToBackdated_Tracer" 'This line and next fail
CurrentDb.QueryDefs("211_AppendToBackdated_Tracer").Execute dbFailOnError
```

I can execute it using DoCmd.OpenQuery and this works, but neither of other methods that should work seem to do as expected.

I get a SQL error so it is trying to run the query.  The error is "Too few parameters. Expected 1."

I would rather use the execute method as this does not require me to turn off system warnings (I want to know if the query fails - not how many records will be added etc.)

Comment: Can you show the SQL?

Comment: Does the query interactively ask for parameter(s), when you open it?

Comment: SQL is too long to fit in the box here.  The SQL contains IIf(Left([FUND_ID],3)="FIP","3442","3433") AS COCD

Comment: So I tried replacing all the " with ' but that did not work.  The query does not expect any parameters when run using docmd openquery

Comment: Add SQL to question's text. Probably you have `Forms![formname]![fieldname]` in SQL text. It is not permitted for `Execute`

Comment: I do - thank you - I will find a work around - btw - is there some way to find this out other than this wonderful site?

Comment: possible workaround is replace with such part:  `Clng(Eval("Forms![formname]![controlWithLongType]"))`  or for dates: `CDate(Eval("Forms![formname]![controlWithDateTimeType]"))`

Comment: @4dmonster: Just pass a value to the parameter. See my answer, please.

Comment: @Gustav you are right, it is better to use `QueryDef` and parameters. Dirty hack with `eval`  was essential only for PIVOT with sub queries.

Answer (score 0):

```
DoCmd.OpenQuery "211_AppendToBackdated_Tracer"   'This line works
```

That's because your query is a *select* query.

```
CurrentDb.Execute "211_AppendToBackdated_Tracer" 'This line and next fail
CurrentDb.QueryDefs("211_AppendToBackdated_Tracer").Execute dbFailOnError
```

That's because the query is not an action query (*update, append, or delete*)

To execute with a parameter:

```
Set qdy = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("211_AppendToBackdated_Tracer")
qdy.Parameter(0).Value = somevalue
qdy.Execute dbFailOnError
```

Comment: Likely issue is interactive parameters per comments. The query's name includes *append*.

Comment: Problem is solver - it is because query included a reference to a form (Forms![formname]![fieldname]).  Can't use this in a execute.  Query is not a select query - that would have returned a different error.

Comment: You can use parameters in action queries. See edited answer, please.